# Need to update Last record of nested array mongoDB c#

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

**I want to update the last object of nested array. Here is my DB structure.**

```
{
  _id:1,
  isActive:true,
  name:xyz,
  student:[
    {
      id:12,
      name:"a",
      dateCreated: "1-1-2022 :20:08:00",
    },
    {
      id:12,
      name:"a",
      dateCreated: "1-1-2022 :22:10:00",
    }
]
```

I'm getting a problem that i have a record with nested array of objects. **I have the same detail of both objects but i want to update the last object of student**. I'm using the below approach which updates my first object of student. I'm unable to find the solution. If anyone have idea let me know.
Thanks in advance

// filter

```
var filter = Builders<UpdateFrameDto>.Filter.Eq(x => x.IsActive, true);

filter &= Builders<UpdateFrameDto>.Filter.ElemMatch(_ => _.student, _ => _.id== 12);

var bBuilder = Builders<UpdateFrameDto>.Update.Set(x => x.student[-1].name, "noman"));
 
var result = _updateFrameCollection.UpdateMany(filter, bBuilder);
```

**Current output**

```
{
  _id:1,
  isActive:true,
  name:xyz,
  student:[
    {
      id:12,
      name:"noman",
      dateCreated: "1-1-2022 :20:08:00",
    },// updating this record
    {
      id:12,
      name:"a",
      dateCreated: "1-1-2022 :22:10:00",
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected output**

```
{
  _id:1,
  isActive:true,
  name:xyz,
  student:[
    {
      id:12,
      name:"a",
      dateCreated: "1-1-2022 :20:08:00",
    },
    {
      id:12,
      name:"noman",
      dateCreated: "1-1-2022 :22:10:00",
    } // want to update this record.
]
```

Comment: Do you want to edit just the last one, or all of them? Your text says 'last one' but your expected results says 'all of them'...

Comment: You can update the last element of the array field using the Update With Aggregation Pipeline feature.

Comment: @nimrodserok  i want to update last record. It was my mistake in text. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could think of to update the actual last item and not just the first item that matches the last item, is:

1. Copy the last item of the array
2. Change the properties of the copy
3. Copy the original array without the last item
4. Add the copied item to the copied array
5. Merge back to the collection

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {lastStudent: {$last: "$student"}}
  },
  { 
    $set: {"lastStudent.name": "noman", count: {$subtract: [{$size: "$student"}, 1]}}
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      reducedStudent: {$slice: ["$student", "$count" ]}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      isActive: 1,
      name: 1,
      student: {$concatArrays: ["$reducedStudent", ["$lastStudent"]]}
    }
  },
  {
    $merge: {
      into: "collection"
    }
  }
])
```

[playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IqHUzFIaA_6).

There are many ways to update the first item that matches, but the actual last item (including the case of duplicates inside the array), is not that straight-forward.

Comment: If it works for you please accept it, so it will be easier for others to find it.